# how to convert date string to time interval in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

how can I convert a preset date string to a time interval? The date string is in the format of `d/m/Y g:i:s A`?

I tried the following, but it returns nothing:

```
$date = ... time format set above ....;
echo strtotime($date); //returns nothing.
```

Sample date - 24/08/2011 11:47:09 PM

Comment: Show us a sample date string.

Comment: Check the question for the edit!

Comment: Switching to Y/m/d seems to work - `echo strtotime( '2011/08/24 11:47:09 AM' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` will not get you the desired result because it assumes `m/d/Y` for the date, see [Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

You could try to [replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) the `/`'s in the date with `-`'s, that would lead to an accepted format but it feels wrong / buggy although it should work if your format is fixed:

```
$new_date = str_replace("/", "-", $string_date);
$timestamp = strtotime($new_date);
```

Comment: Interesting, that´s the first time I´ve got an excepted answer with a negative vote-count. An explanation would be nice though...

Answer (score 1):

If you're on PHP 5.3 or newer you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

For PHP 5.2 you could reformat it to something `strtotime()` can deal with like this:

```
$date = '24/08/2011 11:47:09 PM';
$d = substr($date,6,4).substr($date,3,2).substr($date,0,2).substr($date,10);
$ts = strtotime($d); //1314229629
```

Comment: Then it's probably manual parsing for you. This, or upgrade (it's high time anyway)

Answer (score 0):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php